# Integrating Multiple Codes into One Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba, macos, worksheet-function

I am trying to implement multiple functions into one worksheet_change. I was able to integrate 3 functions before (all pertaining to hiding/unhiding rows), however, am having trouble adding a function that allows multiples selections within a dropdown.

I have tried to add the new multiple selection code to the previously existing code and it does not give me errors, however it wont run. In a perfect world, it would keep the hiding/unhiding functions, as well as allow for multiple selections in the identified rows.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

ActiveSheet.Activate

If Not Application.Intersect(Range("C10:AA10"), Range(Target.Address)) 

Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value

    Case Is = "Select One": Rows("14:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                         Rows("10").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "1": Rows("17:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:16").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "2":  Rows("20:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "3": Rows("23:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:22").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "4":  Rows("26:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:25").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "5": Rows("29:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:28").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "6":  Rows("32:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:31").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "7": Rows("35:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:34").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "8":  Rows("38:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:37").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "9": Rows("41:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:40").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "10":  Rows("44:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:43").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "11": Rows("47:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:46").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "12":  Rows("50:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:49").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "13": Rows("30:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:52").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "14":  Rows("56:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                        Rows("14:55").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    Case Is = "15":  Rows("14:58").EntireRow.Hidden = False
End Select
End If
If Not Intersect(Range("C66:AA66"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case "GBP", "USD", "Yuan", "EUR", "LRD", "Select One"
        Rows("67").Hidden = True
    Case "Other"
        Rows("67").Hidden = False

    End Select
End If
If Not Intersect(Range("C11:AA11"), Target) Is Nothing Then
    Select Case Target.Value
    Case "$"
        Rows("13").Hidden = True
        Rows("12").Hidden = False
    Case "%"
        Rows("13").Hidden = False
        Rows("12").Hidden = True
    Case "Select One"
        Rows("13").Hidden = True
        Rows("12").Hidden = True

    End Select
End If
Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Row = "15",”18”,”21” Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & ", " & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
 Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

I want this to be able to continue hiding/unhiding the given rows based upon selections, as well as allow for multi-selects from the drop downs in the rows outlined in the code. The code does not give me errors, but the multi-select does not run

Comment: Not sure what and why you are trying to do with this code but you have a syntax error - change the relevant line to `If Target.Row = "15" Or Target.Row = ”18” Or Target.Row = "21" Then`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what you're trying to do and I hope these remarks can help your code. So a few comments...

1. [Always use `Option Explicit`](https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/3554/always-use--option-explicit-). No matter what example code you find on the webz, using this habit will be a big help to you in the future.
2. It's a BIG help to use intermediate variables in your code that makes the code self-documenting. There is no penalty for assigning interim values and objects, so use this to your advantage.
3. Separate logic blocks into separate subroutines or functions. This makes your code "functionally isolated" -- meaning that each block of code has a specific focus and if you need to change it, you're only changing it in one location. It also makes your code easier to read without scrolling up and down to get a sense of the overall logic.

In the case of your `Worksheet_Change` event code, I can reduce the logic into a much easier to understand flow:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal target As Range)
    Dim groupsRange As Range
    Dim currencyRange As Range
    Dim valuesRange As Range
    Set groupsRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C10:AA10")
    Set currencyRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C66:AA66")
    Set valuesRange = ActiveSheet.Range("C11:AA11")

    If Not Intersect(groupsRange, target) Is Nothing Then
        ShowActiveGroups target
    ElseIf Not Intersect(currencyRange, target) Is Nothing Then
        ShowCurrency target
    ElseIf Not Intersect(valuesRange, target) Is Nothing Then
        ShowValues target
    End If

    If target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub

    If (target.Row = 15) Or (target.Row = 18) Or (target.Row = 21) Then
        CheckMultiSelect target
    End If
End Sub
```

*Clearly, I may not be getting the "point" of your ranges (using "groups", "currency", "values") but you should use descriptive names that make it easier to understand WHAT and WHY the logic is working on certain sections.*

The code for the `Subs` called in the `Worksheet_Change` event are placed into a separate module and all of them are tagged as `Public`. Each of them have similar logic and there are a few things working here.

4. In each of the logic blocks (i.e. in the `Sub` code in this case) you should go through the steps of establishing **exactly** which worksheet is being referenced. It's critical to always [fully qualify your range references (see #5)](https://www.spreadsheetsmadeeasy.com/7-common-vba-mistakes-to-avoid/). The easiest way to do that (without very long, compound statements) is to use intermediate variables.

So in each of the "Show" routines called above I'm setting up a reference to the `Worksheet` of the target cell (the cell that caused the `Worksheet_Change` event).

```
Dim targetWS As Worksheet
Set targetWS = target.Parent
```

5. Try to define constants for seemingly "random" numbers or values that have no real meaning outside the context of your worksheet.

In your case, you are referencing many different rows and hiding/unhiding them. I have no idea why. But if you could "name" the rows in your code, it could make more sense. Here are some examples I used:

```
Const RED_GROUP_1 As String = "14:58"
Const RED_GROUP_2 As String = "10"
Const GREEN_GROUP_1 As String = "17:58"
Const GREEN_GROUP_2 As String = "14:16"
```

So the first three "Show" routines could look something like this:

```
Public Sub ShowActiveGroups(ByRef target As Range)
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet
    Set targetWS = target.Parent

    Const RED_GROUP_1 As String = "14:58"
    Const RED_GROUP_2 As String = "10"
    Const GREEN_GROUP_1 As String = "17:58"
    Const GREEN_GROUP_2 As String = "14:16"

    With targetWS
        Select Case target.Value
            Case "Select One"
                .Rows(RED_GROUP_1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows(RED_GROUP_2).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case 1
                .Rows(GREEN_GROUP_1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows(GREEN_GROUP_2).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case 2
                .Rows("20:58").EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows("14:19").EntireRow.Hidden = False

            ' ...

            Case Else
                '--- what should we do if it's not a valid value?
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub ShowCurrency(ByRef target As Range)
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet
    Set targetWS = target.Parent

    Const CURRENCY_LINE As String = "67"

    With targetWS
        Select Case target.Value
            Case "GBP", "USD", "Yuan", "EUR", "LRD", "Select One"
                .Rows(CURRENCY_LINE).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Other"
                .Rows(CURRENCY_LINE).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case Else
                '--- what should we do if it's not a valid value?
        End Select
    End With
End Sub

Public Sub ShowValues(ByRef target As Range)
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet
    Set targetWS = target.Parent

    Const MONEY_LINE As String = "13"
    Const PERCENT_LINE As String = "12"

    With targetWS
        Select Case target.Value
            Case "$"
                .Rows(MONEY_LINE).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows(PERCENT_LINE).EntireRow.Hidden = False
            Case "%"
                .Rows(MONEY_LINE).EntireRow.Hidden = False
                .Rows(PERCENT_LINE).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case "Select One"
                .Rows(MONEY_LINE).EntireRow.Hidden = True
                .Rows(PERCENT_LINE).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            Case Else
                '--- what should we do if it's not a valid value?
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Finally, I always had trouble with the data-validation/multi-select code that you found on the [webz](https://trumpexcel.com/select-multiple-items-drop-down-list-excel/). So I'm tossing in the one I use that has a couple slight mods. This code goes in the regular code module as well.

```
Public Sub CheckMultiSelect(ByRef target As Range)
    Dim targetWS As Worksheet
    Set targetWS = target.Parent

    On Error Resume Next
    Dim dvCheck As Range
    Set dvCheck = targetWS.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation)
    If dvCheck Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    '--- only allow multi-select if the cell has defined data validation
    If Not Intersect(dvCheck, target) Is Nothing Then
        Dim currentValue As String
        Dim oldValue As String
        currentValue = target.Value
        Application.Undo
        oldValue = target.Value
        If oldValue = vbNullString Then
            target.Value = currentValue
        Else
            If InStr(1, oldValue, currentValue) = 0 Then
                target.Value = oldValue & "," & currentValue
            Else
                If currentValue = vbNullString Then
                    target.Value = vbNullString
                Else
                    target.Value = oldValue
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End If
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Using the code above in both the worksheet module and a regular code module, I sucessfully was able to perform some of the operations in your original question.

Comment: Apologies for the delay in responding. I have been taking my time to try and understand what you responded so graciously with. I can't thank you enough for this. Not only has it answered my question, but I have learned an immense amount by combing through this. Thank you!!